# Android: How to process multiple onTouch events for views in different viewgroups, in a single gesture

Tags: android

If I touch down on a `View`, and then move passed its borders onto another `View`, the touch event ends (cancels). How can I continue processing the touch event on the next `View` without having to lift my finger up and retouch down onto the adjacent `View`, given that this is all happening within a `ScrollView`?

To prevent the `ScrollView` from scrolling when I move on the views, I have this system set up:

```
mScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return mScrollingDisabled;
    }
});

mTouchableView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mScrollingDisabled=true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mScrollingDisabled=false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mScrollingDisabled=true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mScrollingDisabled=false;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```